# after merge PDFs lose layer settings

Tags: php, pdf, merge, layer, ocg

Is here some tools to merge PDFs with layers?

Tried to merge PDFs with layers with pdftk, fpdf/fpdi, Gswin32c. In any cases output PDF was as simple PDF without layers.

Thanks.

**Edit.** I am looking for tool suitable for use it in PHP project (PHP classes or executables such as pdftk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean Optional Content (section 8.11 of ISO3200-1:2008): AFAIK no free one. There's an unmaintained fork of pdfTeX that has basic support for this, though.

You could try Adobe Acrobat or InDesign.

Answer (score 0):

I think more information about your enviroment is needed, but if you are using .NET I've used [PDFsharp](http://pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/), an open source library, to merge multiple pdf documents with good results.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. Unfortunately PDFsharp not suitable. I am use PHP and should be able run it on linux too.